# A little confusion about SASS which is something comes along with HAML

Tags: ruby, plugins, sass, ruby-on-rails-3

According to [this website](http://sass-lang.com/tutorial.html).  It said that sass will generate css file which is css3
so,here is my concern,what if the browser is not compatible with css3 file.
can I generate css2 file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SASS is simply an alternative syntax for writing CSS which is then compiled into the standard CSS syntax.  This means that your output CSS file will only contain CSS3 properties if you decide to use those properties in your SASS file.

Comment: So,you mean that if I am using IE6 then it will not work with sass?

Comment: Only if you use statements in SASS that are not supported by IE6.  You know that you don't actually server the SASS to the browser, right?  You compile the SASS into CSS.

Comment: you mean if I use css3 properties in my sass file the it will generate css3 file for me.Alright,I have to admit that I need to improve my English

Comment: There is no such thing as a "css3" file or a "css2" file. There are only "css" files. They can have properties in them that are valid in CSS2 or CSS3, but a CSS file is a CSS file.